# MVC - Cascading Dropdown Lists - How to get the selected value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC app with a View that has cascading dropdowns. I have the following Ajax call that retrieves data for the second dropdown, after the user has selected a value in the first dropdown:

```
function GetAutoModel(_manufacturerId) {

    var autoSellerListingId = document.getElementById("AutoSellerListingId").value;

    $.ajax({
        url: "/AutoSellerListing/GetAutoModel/",
        data: { manufacturerId: _manufacturerId, autoSellerListingId: autoSellerListingId },
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            var markup = "<option value='0'>-- Select --</option>";
            for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
                markup += "<option value=" + data[x].Value + ">" + data[x].Text + "</option>";
            }

            $('#ModelList').html(markup).show();
        },
        error: function (reponse) {
            alert("error : " + reponse);
        }
    });
}
```

The following controller code is called to feed the Ajax call data:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetAutoModel(int manufacturerId, int autoSellerListingId)
{
    int modelId = 0;

    // Get all the models associated with the target manufacturer
    List<AutoModel> modelList = this._autoLogic.GetModelListByManufacturer(manufacturerId);

    // If this is an existing listing, get the auto model Id value the seller selected.
    if (autoSellerListingId > 0)
        modelId = this._systemLogic.GetItem<AutoSellerListing>(row => row.AutoSellerListingId == autoSellerListingId).AutoModel.AutoModelId;

    // Convert all the model data to a SelectList and return it
    SelectList returnList = new SelectList(modelList, "AutoModelId", "Description", modelId);

    return Json(returnList);
}
```

Notice the last parameter in the `new SelectList()` call in the controller code (modelId). This is what I want the selected value to be set to once the select object is created in the Ajax call. The problem is that I don't know how to access this value in the client. Everything is working correctly, I just don't know how to access the selected value, and then set it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is that I don't know how to access this value in the client.

You could look at the [`Selected`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlistitem.selected.aspx) boolean property on the client:

```
if (data[x].Selected) {
    markup += "<option value=" + data[x].Value + " selected=\"selected\">" + data[x].Text + "</option>";
} else {
    markup += "<option value=" + data[x].Value + ">" + data[x].Text + "</option>";
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you. I've spent an hour+ on this, and the answer is so simple.

Comment: If you had used a javascript debugging tool such as Firebug or Chrome developper toolbar and looked at the JSON that was returned from the server you would have immediately seen this this property and how it is set to `true` for the corresponding item that needs to be selected.

Comment: Funny you mention this because I was just going to ask you how I could have determined that 'Selected' was a property on the object.

Comment: You could also have looked at the documentation to see that `SelectList` (which is what you are returning) implements `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` and when you looked at the documentation of `SelectListItem` you would have seen the `Selected` property. Now seriously, use a javascript debugging tool if you intend to do any web development :-)

Comment: I actually do use the Chrome developer tools quite extensively. This is the first I've looked at the Network tab, to view the return data from the Ajax call. I haven't been doing browser development all that long.